# Retrieving analytics from local webpages

Tags: google-analytics

I have a series of html pages that form a site that is installed locally on a customers machine. I would like to track their use of our site with analytics (googles or otherwise) to get a sense of where they are navigating, what they are looking at, etc.

I'm new to the concept of analytics on a webpage and want to know if there is a way to run these analytics on a local machine. Specifically, can this tracking information be accumulated locally on a customers machine and then uploaded with a separate application, i.e. it cannot be a requirement that these webpages have access to the internet. It would be ideal to create a dump or copy of the information accumulated that could then be sent off via another tool.

Thank you for all your help,
Dirk7589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE:- Customer's machine must have internetconnectivity 
You need to include analytics.js script in all html pages before closing of head tag, or while using framework like rails put it in your main template so it loads every time a user opens a new page.Also remember you need to send page view separately for ajax call. 
[USE THIS LINK FOR REFRENCE](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)

**Below code is analytics.js:-**

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Then go to your google analytics ACCOUNT AND TRACK FLOW IN LEFT HAND SIDE 
***BEHAVIOR > BEHAVIOR FLOW***

Comment: Thank you for the information, this is what I was looking for. Unfortunately it would appear that google analytics will not solve my problem. Thanks for your help.